# Meteor Android permissions

Tags: cordova, meteor, ionic-framework, meteoric

I'm working on a mobile app built in Meteor and Meteoric (that got discontinued just recently, I'm aware of that). Most of the things are working nicely, but geolocation provides issues on Android devices.

It reports that the required permissions are not available. I can fix that by adding those permissions to the `AndroidManifest.xml` file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
```

The issue is that the `AndroidManifest.xml` file is in `gitignore` (actually, it's hidden somewhere below `.meteor/local`, and that is in `gitignore`). Manually updating the `AndroidManifest.xml` does work, but that means every member of my team needs to do it. And if someone joins the team later, we get the same issue again. Also it's not really a solution for automated deployment if we have to update the file manually.

How should I configure Meteor / Meteoric so these permissions get added to my Android app?

Comment: can you install cordova plugins on meteor apps? if you can, install the geolocation plugin, it should add the permissions. If not, you can search for plugins that write values on the AndroidManifest.xml from the config.xml

Comment: @jcesarmobile: After your comment I noticed that the permissions are working for other plugins. And using an updated version for the geolocation plugin seems to solve the problem, the permissions now do appear in `AndroidManifest.xml`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated the geolocation plugin and that has fixed the permissions issue. I don't know if that's because of the update itself or some side effect, but at least it solved my problems.